# Keyboard module doesn't work in a tkinter Gui

Tags: python, tkinter, keyboard

I wanted to create a keyboard whose keys were 
colored when I pressed the key on the keyboard.
The code has no errors, but when the button is pressed, nothing happens:
I don't now if is possible to do that keyboard with that module or i made some errors.
Please, help me.

```
import tkinter as tk
import keyboard


class SensibleKeyboard:

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.title("Sensible Keyboard")
        self.root.resizable(False,False)
        self.root.geometry("520x265")

        #Titolo
        self.title = tk.Label(text = "SensibleKeyboard",font = ("Arial",26)).place(x = 120 ,y = 10)

        #Frame contenitore tastiera
        self.frame = tk.Frame(width = 520, height = 165, bg = "#fff")
        self.frame.place(x = 0, y = 100)

        #Tastiera grafica
        #Riga 1
        self.q =  tk.Button(self.frame,text = "Q", height = 3, width = 6, activebackground = "black", activeforeground = "white").place(x = 0 , y = 0)
        self.w =  tk.Button(self.frame,text = "W", height = 3, width = 6, activebackground = "black", activeforeground = "white").place(x = 52 , y = 0)
        self.e =  tk.Button(self.frame,text = "E", height = 3, width = 6, activebackground = "black", activeforeground = "white").place(x = 104 , y = 0)
        self.r =  tk.Button(self.frame,text = "R", height = 3, width = 6, activebackground = "black", activeforeground = "white").place(x = 156 , y = 0)
        self.t =  tk.Button(self.frame,text = "T", height = 3, width = 6, activebackground = "black", activeforeground = "white").place(x = 208 , y = 0)
        self.y =  tk.Button(self.frame,text = "Y", height = 3, width = 6, activebackground = "black", activeforeground = "white").place(x = 260 , y = 0)
        self.u =  tk.Button(self.frame,text = "U", height = 3, width = 6, activebackground = "black", activeforeground = "white").place(x = 312 , y = 0)
        self.i =  tk.Button(self.frame,text = "I", height = 3, width = 6, activebackground = "black", activeforeground = "white").place(x = 364 , y = 0)
        self.o =  tk.Button(self.frame,text = "O", height = 3, width = 6, activebackground = "black", activeforeground = "white").place(x = 416 , y = 0)
        self.p =  tk.Button(self.frame,text = "P", height = 3, width = 6, activebackground = "black", activeforeground = "white").place(x = 468 , y = 0)

        #Riga 2
        self.a =  tk.Button(self.frame,text = "A", height = 3, width = 6, activebackground = "black", activeforeground = "white").place(x = 17 , y = 56)
        self.s =  tk.Button(self.frame,text = "S", height = 3, width = 6, activebackground = "black", activeforeground = "white").place(x = 69 , y = 56)
        self.d =  tk.Button(self.frame,text = "D", height = 3, width = 6, activebackground = "black", activeforeground = "white").place(x = 121 , y = 56)
        self.f =  tk.Button(self.frame,text = "F", height = 3, width = 6, activebackground = "black", activeforeground = "white").place(x = 173 , y = 56)
        self.g =  tk.Button(self.frame,text = "G", height = 3, width = 6, activebackground = "black", activeforeground = "white").place(x = 225 , y = 56)
        self.h =  tk.Button(self.frame,text = "H", height = 3, width = 6, activebackground = "black", activeforeground = "white").place(x = 277 , y = 56)
        self.j =  tk.Button(self.frame,text = "J", height = 3, width = 6, activebackground = "black", activeforeground = "white").place(x = 329 , y = 56)
        self.k =  tk.Button(self.frame,text = "K", height = 3, width = 6, activebackground = "black", activeforeground = "white").place(x = 381 , y = 56)
        self.l =  tk.Button(self.frame,text = "L", height = 3, width = 6, activebackground = "black", activeforeground = "white").place(x = 433 , y = 56)

        #Riga 3
        self.z =  tk.Button(self.frame,text = "Z", height = 3, width = 6, activebackground = "black", activeforeground = "white").place(x = 40 , y = 112)
        self.x =  tk.Button(self.frame,text = "X", height = 3, width = 6, activebackground = "black", activeforeground = "white").place(x = 92 , y = 112)
        self.c =  tk.Button(self.frame,text = "C", height = 3, width = 6, activebackground = "black", activeforeground = "white").place(x = 144 , y = 112)
        self.v =  tk.Button(self.frame,text = "V", height = 3, width = 6, activebackground = "black", activeforeground = "white").place(x = 196 , y = 112)
        self.b =  tk.Button(self.frame,text = "B", height = 3, width = 6, activebackground = "black", activeforeground = "white").place(x = 248 , y = 112)
        self.n =  tk.Button(self.frame,text = "N", height = 3, width = 6, activebackground = "black", activeforeground = "white").place(x = 300 , y = 112)
        self.m =  tk.Button(self.frame,text = "M", height = 3, width = 6, activebackground = "black", activeforeground = "white").place(x = 352 , y = 112)

        #Funzione accensione da tastiera
        #Funzioni
        if keyboard.is_pressed("q"):
            self.q.config(bg = "blue")
        elif keyboard.is_pressed("w"):
            self.w.config(bg = "blue")
        elif keyboard.is_pressed("e"):
            self.e.config(bg = "blue")
        elif keyboard.is_pressed("r"):
            self.r.config(bg = "blue")
        elif keyboard.is_pressed("t"):
            self.t.config(bg = "blue")
        elif keyboard.is_pressed("y"):
            self.y.config(bg = "blue")
        elif keyboard.is_pressed("u"):
            self.u.config(bg = "blue")
        elif keyboard.is_pressed("i"):
            self.i.config(bg = "blue")
        elif keyboard.is_pressed("o"):
            self.o.config(bg = "blue")
        elif keyboard.is_pressed("p"):
            self.p.config(bg = "blue")
        elif keyboard.is_pressed("a"):
            self.a.config(bg = "blue")
        elif keyboard.is_pressed("s"):
            self.s.config(bg = "blue")
        elif keyboard.is_pressed("d"):
            self.d.config(bg = "blue")
        elif keyboard.is_pressed("f"):
            self.f.config(bg = "blue")
        elif keyboard.is_pressed("g"):
            self.g.config(bg = "blue")
        elif keyboard.is_pressed("h"):
            self.h.config(bg = "blue")
        elif keyboard.is_pressed("j"):
            self.j.config(bg = "blue")
        elif keyboard.is_pressed("k"):
            self.k.config(bg = "blue")
        elif keyboard.is_pressed("l"):
            self.l.config(bg = "blue")
        elif keyboard.is_pressed("z"):
            self.z.config(bg = "blue")
        elif keyboard.is_pressed("x"):
            self.x.config(bg = "blue")
        elif keyboard.is_pressed("c"):
            self.c.config(bg = "blue")
        elif keyboard.is_pressed("v"):
            self.v.config(bg = "blue")
        elif keyboard.is_pressed("b"):
            self.b.config(bg = "blue")
        elif keyboard.is_pressed("n"):
            self.n.config(bg = "blue")
        elif keyboard.is_pressed("m"):
            self.m.config(bg = "blue")
        else:
            pass     
    def start(self):
        self.root.mainloop()
sk = SensibleKeyboard()
sk.start()
```

Comment: Why not simple use the button on click event to color the buttons?

Comment: Also do you want the colors to change back to default when no longer pressed?

Comment: Aside from the whole keyboard issue, is there any reason not to use a list and loops to handle all the buttons, rather than repeating so much code?

Comment: @AMC I managed to build everything in a loop. Only concerned I had was the half tab spacing for each row but that was easy to handle with padding per row. The OP probably didnt know they could build this in a loop.

Comment: @Mike-SMT yes, the color should return to the default one. How can i use a loop?

Comment: Thanks for all, i need your answer

Comment: @Mike-SMT i don't use the onclick event because i want to use the keyboard.

Comment: Poss, The events can also monitor the key presses on the keyboard. Take a look at my answer for an example.

Comment: @Mike-SMT thank you so much

Comment: @Poss if my answer solved your problem please select the check mark next to the answer to show your issue is resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need the keyboard library to handle this.

First lets fix your very redundant code. Instead of writing each button one at a time we can do this in a dynamic way based on a list of characters. At the same time we can store our buttons in a list that we can use to update the buttons on click.

With the use of `bind()` we can check if one of the keys was press and then update the corresponding button in the list.

By binding all Key Presses and all Key Releases we can use a method to check if one of those keys was from our list and if so update the button on key press and key release.

```
import tkinter as tk


class SensibleKeyboard(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("Sensible Keyboard")
        self.resizable(False, False)
        self.geometry("520x265")
        self.title = tk.Label(text="SensibleKeyboard",
                              font=("Arial", 26)).grid(row=0, column=0, pady=20, sticky='ew')
        main_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        main_frame.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='ew')
        self.orig_color = self.cget("background")
        self.btn_list = []
        btn_rows = ['QWERTYUIOP', 'ASDFGHJKL', 'ZXCVBNM']
        row_pad = 0
        btn_ndex = 0
        for ndex, rows in enumerate(btn_rows):
            row_frame = tk.Frame(main_frame)
            row_frame.grid(row=ndex, column=0, sticky='ew', padx=(row_pad,0))
            row_pad += 20
            for row_ndex, value in enumerate([char for char in rows]):
                self.btn_list.append(tk.Button(row_frame, text=value, height=3, width=6,
                                               activebackground="black", activeforeground="white"))
                self.btn_list[-1].grid(row=0, column=row_ndex)
                btn_ndex += 1
        self.bind('<KeyPress>', lambda e: self.change_bg(e, 'p'))
        self.bind('<KeyRelease>', lambda e: self.change_bg(e, 'r'))

    def change_bg(self, event, press_type):
        print(event)
        c = event.char.upper()
        for btn_ndex, value in enumerate([char for char in 'QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM']):
            if value == c:
                if press_type == 'p':
                    self.btn_list[btn_ndex].config(bg='blue')
                else:
                    self.btn_list[btn_ndex].config(bg=self.orig_color)
                break


if __name__ == '__main__':
    SensibleKeyboard().mainloop()
```